# Windows Batch FOR Loop improvement

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch to check the duplicate line in TXT file (over one million line) with 13MB, that will be running over 2hr...how can I speed up that? Thank you!!

**TXT file**

```
11
22
33
44
.
.
.
44 (over one million line)
```

**Existing Batch**

```
setlocal
set var1=*
sort original.txt>sort.txt
for /f %%a in ('type sort.txt') do (call :run %%a)
goto :end
:run
if %1==%var1% echo %1>>duplicate.txt
set var1=%1
goto :eof
:end
```

Comment: Use PowerShell?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Or no CLI at all

Comment: Only try running with BAT file...Could you show me the powershell code about that?

Comment: I testing with powershell code ( $lines = @(); Get-Content 1.txt | %{ if (($lines -eq $_).length -eq 0) {$lines = $lines + $_}}; $lines > done
.txt) and still running over 45mins...not yet done

Comment: `Get-Content .\example.txt | Group-Object | Where { $_.Count -ne 1 }`

Comment: Reported times of some solutions: Original code: 2 hours 40 minutes.  [aschipfl's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42575264/778560): 12 hours.  [Magoo's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42575261/778560): 2 hours.  [PowerShell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574625/windows-batch-for-loop-improvement#comment72284862_42574625): 45+ minutes.  [Aacini's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42576258/778560): 1 minute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the fastest method using a Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var1=*
sort original.txt>sort.txt
(for /f %%a in (sort.txt) do (
   if "%%a" == "!var1!" (
      echo %%a
   ) else (
      set "var1=%%a"
   )
)) >duplicate.txt
```

Comment: Since `sort` works case-insensitively, there might be some duplicates not detected: imagine three lines `duplicate`, `Duplicate`, `duplicate`; your script is not going to report duplicates, unless you add `/I` to your `if` query; if the OP wants a case-sensitive approach, `sort` will not help... _(this is not a [revenge comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574625/windows-batch-for-loop-improvement/42575264#comment72285883_42575264) ;-))_

Comment: @aschipfl: I suppose you are right, although the original code have not the `/I` switch and the example data are just numbers... Just the OP may clear this point. And talking about _revenges_, I invite you to review [my new solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42578073/778560)! **`;)`**

Comment: Just to clear this point: are you saying that your original method took over 2 hr, the PowerShell method took over 45 mins, and my solution took 1 min? Using _the same_ data file?  **`:)`**  I'll appreciate it if you post here the times in `HH:MM:SS` format of _all_ methods posted here that you have tested...

Comment: Ah! And please do an additional test changing this line: `sort original.txt>sort.txt` by this one: `sort original.txt /O sort.txt`

Answer (score 2):

This method use `findstr` command as in aschipfl's answer, but in this case each line and its duplicates are removed from the file after being revised by `findstr`. This method *could be* faster if the number of duplicates in the file is high; otherwise it will be slower because the high volume data manipulated in each turn. Just a test may confirm this point...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

del duplicate.txt 2>NUL
copy /Y original.txt input.txt > NUL

:nextTurn
for %%a in (input.txt) do if %%~Za equ 0 goto end

< input.txt (
   set /P "line="
   findstr /X /C:"!line!"
   find /V "!line!" > output.txt
) >> duplicate.txt

move /Y output.txt input.txt > NUL
goto nextTurn

:end
```

Comment: Although I am not sure whether `find /V "!line!"` should be replaced by `findstr /V /X /C:"!line!"`, I like this method because it does not loop through the text file line by line; +1...

Comment: @aschipfl: The `findstr` command get duplicates and output they to `duplicate.txt`. The `find` command delete duplicates and store the rest of lines in `output.txt`. Further details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/28278628#28278628)

Comment: Since you want to handle whole lines, `findstr /X` is needed; `find` also matches in case the search string is found in the middle of a line...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=*
(
for /f %%a in ('sort q42574625.txt') do (
 if "%%a"=="!var1!" echo %%a
 set "var1=%%a"
)
)>"u:\q42574625_2.txt"

GOTO :EOF
```

This may be faster - I don't have your file to test against

I used a file named `q42574625.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

It's not clear whether you want only one instance of a duplicate line or not. Your code would produce 5 "duplicate" lines if there were 6 identical lines in the source file.

Here's a version which will report each duplicated line only once:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=*
set var2=*
(
for /f %%a in ('sort q42574625.txt') do (
 if "%%a"=="!var1!" IF "!var2!" neq "%%a" echo %%a&SET "var2=%%a"
 set "var1=%%a"
)
)>"u:\q42574625.txt"

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, I trying and report you once done!

Comment: Your code is faster than me (you: 120 minutes i: 160 minutes) ... but i want to finish in 30 minutes ... but i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you provide the text file as the first command line argument, you could try the following:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%~1") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%K in ('
        findstr /X /C:"%%L" "%~1" ^| find /C /V ""
    ') do (
        if %%K GTR 1 echo %%L
    )
)
```

This returns all duplicate lines, but multiple times each, namely as often as each occurs in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your code, I trying and report you once done!

Comment: I am pretty sure that this method will be _slower_ than the original. You are running _three copies_ of cmd.exe (one for the nested `for /F` command and one more for each side of the pipe) plus `findstr.exe` (that process the _entire_ file) plus `find.exe`, for _each line_ of the file!

Comment: @Aacini, yes, you might be right, I guess. I did not test it, but my thought was that the `findstr` command might be faster than `for /F` containing `if` comparisons and sub-routine `call`s.